# The difference between "since I have known" and "since I knew her"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, present-perfect, past-simple

1. It's been ten years since I have known her.
2. It's been ten years since I knew her.

My understanding is that 1 is the same as

- I have known her for ten years.
- It's been ten years since I got to know her.
- It's been ten years since I first met her.

and 2 is the same as

- It's been ten years since I last met her.
- I haven't been in touch with her for the past ten years.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Your three alternatives for (1) are all much more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

I think "since I knew her" sounds off in this sense (at least in my particular Anglo-Irish dialect).

Unless 'since' is being used as a synonym for 'because' (or 'knew' is being used "in the biblical sense", which is popularly taken to mean "had sex with her"). :-|

The reason is that 'know' is neither an action verb nor something that happens at a discrete moment of time. It is a disposition. And it's one that the speaker clearly still has (since they're speaking about her).

There is of course the comic/tragic song (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_I_Hardly_Knew_Ye) but that sense is from an old Anglo-Irish dialect and means more or less "recognise."

For the meaning you describe, I'd say most native speakers of standard or near-standard English would put something like "last met/saw/spoke to" where you put "knew".

The other (possibly more important) problem with "since I knew her" in your sense is that it's far too easy to misunderstand the speaker; thinking they mean "since I've known her."